# Uppy doesn't appear on the screen in rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby

I'm trying to do a very simple app just to test the Uppy file uploader. I've followed the Uppy's documentation, but it just worked with the library links (CDN).

I've already tried `npm install @uppy/core` (and the same command for the additional plugins). I've already tried to put the code inside my coffee file (I'm using ruby on rails). And other things too, but no results.

Here's my code:

```
import '@uppy/core/dist/style.css'
import '@uppy/dashboard/dist/style.css'

Uppy = require('uppy/lib/core')

Dashboard = require('uppy/lib/plugins/Dashboard')

uppy = Uppy({ autoProceed: false })

uppy.use(Dashboard, { target: '#drag-drop-area', inline: true })
```

This is actually throwing no errors, just doesn't appear on the screen.

Comment: that drag-drop-area exists inside a partial

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer. It happens that you actually need to use a bundler in order to make the 'require' works in the browser. This is not explicit in uppy's documentation, but I guess I should already know it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to add the new keyword when initializing Uppy.
This is from the [documentation](https://uppy.io/docs/uppy/) .
So instead `uppy = Uppy({ autoProceed: false })` it should be `const uppy = new Uppy({autoProceed: false})`

Hope that helps.

P.s I think that is for the new versions of Uppy.